# How to find percentage of a value in a column by grouping by other multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find the percentage of rows in a column that has a certain value. And find the percentage for each combination of two other columns.

Here is a example df:

```
data =[['North Shields','UK','Y'],['North Shields','Foreign','N']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Port','Type','Shellfish Licence licence (Y/N)']
df
```

i have tried the following but get a key error, probably because i cant grouby two columns in this way.

```
port_shel_df = landing_fish_merge['Shellfish Licence licence 
(Y/N)'].eq('Y').groupby(port_merge_lic_df['Port','Type]).mean().reset_index(name='Shellfish 
license 
percentage')
port_shel_df = port_shel_df.set_index('Port')
port_shel_df[:1]
```

Comment: Can you provide some expected results?

Comment: A dataframe including the port, the type (UK or foreign) and the shellfish percentage of 'Y' ,expected results will be a dataframe like so:  `data =[['North Shields','UK','.45'],['North Shields','Foreign','0.23']] df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Port','Type','Shellfish percentage']
df  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper column and aggregate by it:

```
df = (landing_fish_merge.assign(new= landing_fish_merge['Shellfish Licence licence (Y/N)'].eq('Y'))
                        .groupby(['Port','Type'])['new'].mean()
                        .reset_index(name='Shellfish license percentage'))
```